# I am trying to install puppeteer in the VSC terminal funding

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, puppeteer

I am trying to install puppeteer in the VSC terminal, but whenever i run the install in npm, it does not download and says something needs funding. Help!!

```
npm i puppeteer

up to date, audited 67 packages in 5s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's *already* installed successfully...? I mean, `up to date` is pretty telling that this is the case. If so, why would it download *again*? "*it [...] says something needs funding.*" What does this message have *anything* to do with your issue, exactly?

Comment: Well, i have watched alot of tutorials and they have a particular JSON file automatically downloaded, and the process is all different from mine, so i dont think i downlaoded it. Please help me download it??

Comment: "*they have a particular JSON file automatically downloaded*" *What* JSON are you referring to? "*Please help me download it??*" How can we possibly help you do so if you've already downloaded it...?

Comment: Well, i watched a tutorial about downloading it, and when it was downloading, it automatically added new files to the .vscode folder, but when i try downloading it, it just dosent appear, so i think it didnt download and there was some glitch with the node.js or npm.

Comment: Have you checked the output of the commands `npm list` and `npm list -g`? Does `puppeteer` appear in either list? If so, on *what* information/data are you basing your assumption that "*it didnt download and there was some glitch with the node.js or npm*"? If not, have you tried un-installing and re-installing the package/Node.js/npm? If so, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Your `puppeteer` package and `node_modules` are already downloaded.
You can test it by simply run this inside `node` console:

```
C:\> node

    Welcome to Node.js v16.14.0.
    Type ".help" for more information.

> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
    undefined
> puppeteer
    PuppeteerNode {
      _changedProduct: false,
      _isPuppeteerCore: false,
      _projectRoot: 'C:\Users\username\NodeJS\pptrdev\',
      __productName: undefined,
      _preferredRevision: '961656'
    }
> .exit
```

If you means .JSON file, then probably referring to the `packages.json`.